# написать алгоритм и программу вычисления функции

Tags: pascal

написать алгоритм и программу вычисления функции Z = SUM(F3(x))
Значения аргумента х функции f3 заданы интервалом целых значений отрезка [a3,b3]. Шаг изменений значений аргумента принять равным 1. Данные для решения представлены в таблице.
Вариант 3

Сам в математике ничего не понимаю, так что прошу помощи здесь)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: без ваших усилий никто вам не ответит.

Comment: Я бы не отказался даже от краткого разъяснения процесса решения этой задачи, я в целом условие не могу понять.

Comment: Краткое разъяснение. Для первой строчки таблицы нужно найти сумму чисел `10^5`, `11^5` и `12^5`.

Comment: а что не понятно? у вас 3 вариант - функция x^3, отрезок [12, 18], шаг 1. используйте цикл для суммирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот псевдокод:

```
x := 12
пока x <= 18:
    сумма := сумма + x*x*x
    x := x + 1
вывод сумма
```